# Can we solve KL divergence between Gaussian Mixtures by thinking conditional cases?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I learned that KL divergence between two Gaussian Mixtures is intractable, not easy to solve.
But I am wondering if we can solve it by thinking conditional cases?

Let's say, a single multivariate Gaussian and a 2-mixture multivariate Gaussian as shown below.
$$
g_{A}=Gauss(\mu_A,\sigma_A )
$$
$$
g_{B+C}=w_B\cdot Gauss(\mu_B,\sigma_B )+w_C\cdot Gauss(\mu_C,\sigma_C )
$$
Is KL divergence below correct?

$$
D_{KL} \left( g_{A}\right| \left| g_{B+C} \right)=w_B\cdot D_{KL} \left( g_{A}\right| \left| g_{B} \right)+w_C\cdot D_{KL} \left( g_{A}\right| \left| g_{C} \right)
$$

seeing weights $w_B$ ,$w_C$ as conditional probabilities, $P(D_{KL}|g_B)$,$P(D_{KL}|g_C)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the KL divergence $D(p||q)$ is convex in the pair $(p,q)$ so the equation you wrote holds as an inequality:
$$
D_{KL} \left( g_{A}\right| \left| g_{B+C} \right)\leq w_B\cdot D_{KL} \left( g_{A}\right| \left| g_{B} \right)+w_C\cdot D_{KL} \left( g_{A}\right| \left| g_{C} \right)
$$
See [this paper by Hershey and Olsen](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4f8d/eabc58014eae708c3e6ee27114535325067b.pdf) and also [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36005/what-is-the-distance-between-a-finite-gaussian-mixture-and-a-gaussian) on related material for approximating the KL between mixtures of distributions.